# How to make c# wait until previous code has been executed?

Tags: c#

This is probably a simple little thing, but I can't figure it out...
I have a method in my code with a very simple statement:

```
 if (check == 1) 
{
labelTest.Text = "Loading, please wait."
retrieveData()
}
```

In the 'retrieveData' method, a huge bulk of data is retrieved from a database and some listviews are populated. This takes a couple of seconds, so I want the 'Loading' text to be visible.

What happens, though, when (check == 1) is true, the method 'retrieveData' will execute and THEN the labelTest.Text changes to "Loading, please wait."

What can I do to make it run in the proper order, so first finish the first line in the IF statement and THEN move on to the second?
I even tried a very dirty workaround (System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)), as to give the text a second to load, but even that didn't work.

Comment: What technology is that? ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF, something else?

Comment: If you are able to use C# 5, use of async/await would work here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: If this is in WinForms/WPF/similar, you're doing a lot of work on the UI thread - not a good idea...

Comment: Your problem is that you're running `retriveData()` on the UI thread. Move it to its own thread and the form updating can take place while the work is being preformed.

Comment: You are doing a lot of work on the GUI thread, so that thread is consumed doing your work and has no time to update the UI.  Once your work is done, the thread is freed up and then the UI updates.  The best way around this is to do as @CoreyLarson says and use async/await.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Can you give me a little more help please? I don't have any experience with async methods and I'm not sure how to use the info I found on it. What should I change in my code? The method retrieveData() is currently a void, it does not need to return anything. Can you give me a little example, perhaps?
I'm using C# in VS2012 to build a Windows Form application btw.

Comment: If you have difficulties understanding the control flow when using async/await, you might want to look at MSDN documentation: [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you're using C# 5, you'd want to do this via `async`:

```
if (check == 1)
{
    labelTest.Text = "Loading, please wait."
    // ideally make this an async method:
    await retrieveDataAsync();
    // if that's not an option:
    // await Task.Run(() => retrieveDataAsync());
    labelTest.Text = "Done."
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code executes in the order that you expect, the first statement is completed before the second starts.

However, the first statement doesn't update the display of the label, it only changes the text of the label and creates a message that the label needs to be redrawn. As the code is running in the main thread there is nothing that will handle the message until the method exits.

The simple solution is to force the redrawing of the control:

```
labelTest.Text = "Loading, please wait.";
labelTest.Update();
retrieveData();
```

This will redraw the label so that the message is shown, but the application is still unresponsive while the data is loading. To keep the application responsive, you would start a new thread to do the work, or use `async` as Reed Copsey suggests in his answer.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. Perhaps this isn't best practice, but it looks like a simple solution to my problem for now.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps there are better solutions, but for my problem, this worked just fine.